# How could the ellipsoid formula form a 2-sheeted hyperboloid?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d

According to the sources, the ellipsoid formula is:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
And the formula for a 2-sheeted hyperboloid is:
$$-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
Now I have this problem with its respective solution:

> $F(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$
> This surface is the lower part of a hyperboloid of two sheets; the function's domain is $\mathbb R^2$ and its range is the interval $(-\infty,-1]$.
> [image]

But if you rearrange the equation you would get
$$z^2=1-x^2-y^2$$
$$1=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
Which is the formula for an ellipsoid, not a hyperboloid. But I checked the graph of the answer with software and it's correct. How is this possible?

Comment: I think this is due to a simple sign error.

Comment: How did software tell you the graph was correct? I tried it [with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=F%28x%2Cy%29%3D%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2-y%5E2%7D) and that software says the function is real only on the unit circle and the plot over that domain is half a sphere.

Comment: You are right. The book is wrong somehow. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be merely a typo. To reproduce the given hyperboloid and domain and range the surface should be
$$z=-\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$$
A more prosaic reason for the error is that the function does not actually refer to the plot.

Comment: The formula gives some kind of hyperboloid. But with a different domain. I think you are right in that there is an error. But my question is about the shape, not the  domain.